# The efficiency between ProcessPoolExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, tree, multiprocessing

Efficient summation of a list involves parallelizing the addition process while maintaining the order.  The objective is to create a hierarchical structure resembling a tree, where adjacent nodes are continuously added until a single node remains.  I have experimented with both **ProcessPoolExecutor** and **ThreadPoolExecutor** in pursuit of optimal performance on a device equipped with 8 CPUs.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

add_list = list(range(100))
temp_len = len(add_list)


loop_start = time.time()
max_node_num = 0

while temp_len > 1 :
    is_odd = temp_len%2

    group_len = int(temp_len/2 + is_odd)
    group = [(2*i, 2*i+1) for i in range(group_len - is_odd)]

    if is_odd == 1:
        last = add_list[-1]

    def group_cont(group):
        add_item = add_list[group[0]] + add_list[group[1]]

        return add_item

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(group_cont, group)

    # with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    #     results = executor.map(group_cont, group)


    add_list = []
    for result in results:
        add_list.append(result)
    if is_odd == 1:
        add_list.append(last)
    temp_len = group_len

loop_end = time.time() 
print(f'Time: {round(loop_end-loop_start,3)}')
```

Output: Time: 0.012

"For ProcessPoolExecutor Time: 0.271"

Why the **ThreadPoolExecutor** is much more efficient than **ProcessPoolExecutor**? How to make ProcessPoolExecutor more efficient?

Comment: as I know always system (Windows, Linux, Mac) needs more time to create `Process`  than `Thread`. And threads may share memory to send data. Processes may have to write data on disk to send data.

Comment: The code you have is insanely inefficient (try comparing it with a normal for loop that adds numbers tothether, it'll be faster). The reason why process pool executor is slower is you're not passing a chunk size, meaning a new process is created for every 2 numbers that you add. Processes create a complete copy of their parent process to have access to the program state, which is slow. @furas is wrong about using disk to send data, but lots of memory copies will be slow regardless. The problem with thread pool executor is the GIL that prevents multiple threads from accessing the same object.

Comment: @OM222O I often see questions about processes which have problem with pickling data - so I was thinking that it sends by disk - but I checked in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) and it sends pickled data by queue or pipe. So you are right. (but I'm not sure if `pipe` sometimes use disk to send data)

Comment: @furas that only happens if you're out of memory and you have allocated some disk capacity as a swap space, so it almost never happens.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is much more efficient than `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

As explained in the comments, this is because the overheads of creating processes and copying data between the processes in the latter exceeds the corresponding overheads in the former.  Apparently, by a factor of 20 or so.

And this is despite the fact that the threads in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` version are most likely only using a one core (at a time) due to the GIL issue.

Note that the data is not transferred via disk files.  It is actually transferred via a pipe (in current implementations).  Even so, the overheads of serializing, writing, reading and deserializing a small object is orders of magnitude larger than passing a reference from one thread to another.

> How to make `ProcessPoolExecutor` more efficient?

In this example, **you most likely can't**.

The real problem is that this is a bad example for testing parallelism<sup>1</sup>.  Basically, the work in each parallel task is minuscule.  Even under ideal circumstances, the overheads of dispatching each task to the another thread and getting the results back far exceed any possible speedup from (ideally) using multiple cores.

On the other hand, if the work performed by a task was a couple of orders of magnitude larger, you would probably find that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` version was faster.

---

<sup>1 - The characterization of your test code as "insanely inefficient" is apt, IMO.</sup>